# JScrollPanel is not responding initially

Tags: java, swing

I wanted to make a chat server client with GUI. Any new messages will be added as a JPanel. Initially messages added to my JScrollPanel is updating smoothly. However when i implemented the server and client to work with the GUI, the first few new messages added are never updated. Messages will only be updated to the JScrollPanel after the third add onward. Some times the adding of components ended prematurely. The client implements runnable so any new messages will be updated to the JScrollPanel via a Thread.
It seems like the GUI did not fully initialise.

this is the Client code

```js
public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Thread(new MessageClient("htf0001")).start();
        MessageGUI dialog = new MessageGUI(collaID);
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        //loop read from server
        // The default port.
        int portNumber = 50000;
        // The default host.
        String host =  "localhost";//"54.169.62.79";        
        /*
        * Open a socket on a given host and port. Open input and output streams.
        */
        try {
            clientSocket = new Socket(host, portNumber);
            oos = new ObjectOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
            oos.flush();
            ois = new ObjectInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
            
            Staff staff = new Staff();
            sendToServer(staff.connectToMessageServer(collaID));
            sendToServer(staff.getMessageLog(collaID));
            
            while(!close){
                ArrayList<String> input = new ArrayList<String>();
                Object o = ois.readObject();
                input = (ArrayList<String>) o;
                if(input.get(0).compareTo("end")!=0){
                    for(int i=0;i<input.size();i=i+5){
                        MessageGUI.addMessage(input.get(i),input.get(i+1), input.get(i+2),
                                          input.get(i+3),input.get(i+4));
                    }
                }
                else close = true;
            }
            oos.close();
            ois.close();
            clientSocket.close();
        }
        catch (UnknownHostException uhe) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,uhe.getMessage());
        } 
        catch (IOException ioe) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,ioe.getMessage());
        } 
        catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

this is the GUI code part that add in the component

```js
public static void addMessage(String date, String firstName, String lastName,
                            String message, String time){
        String newUser = firstName + " " + lastName;
        
        if(recentDate.compareTo(date)!=0){
            JLabel newDate = new JLabel(date);
            newDate.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
            addComponent(newDate,nextLine,0,3,1);
            recentDate = date;
            nextLine++;
        }
        
        if(recentUser.compareTo(newUser)==0 && recentTime.compareTo(time)==0){
            recentJTextArea.append("\n\n"+message);
        }
        else{
            if(recentUser.compareTo(newUser)==0) newUser = recentUser;
            JTextArea temp = new JTextArea();
            temp.setFocusable(false);
            temp.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(newUser));
            temp.setLineWrap(true);
            temp.setWrapStyleWord(true);
            temp.setEditable(false);
            temp.setText(message);
            recentJTextArea = temp;
            recentUser = newUser;

            JLabel newTime = new JLabel(time);
            newTime.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.RIGHT);
            recentTime = time;

            addComponent(temp,nextLine,0,2,1);
            nextLine = nextLine + 1;
            addComponent(newTime,nextLine,1,1,1);
            nextLine = nextLine + 1;
            
            
        }
        invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                ChatLogJScrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar().setValue(ChatLogJScrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar().getMaximum());
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are updating (ie adding the chat text) to your text areas on a thread that is not the GUI thread. Instead, you should call

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
  temp.setText(message);
  temp.repaint();
});
```

Comment: temp.repaint(); is for painting or notifier for LayoutManager, not for JTextComponent

Comment: the chat area is in this format

JPanel contatiner
JScrollPanel(container)

any new messages will update the container
by adding a new JTextArea.

i tried repaint() nth works

only after first 2 new message added then everything will run smoothly. subsequent new messages will updated smoothly only after first 2 message added. i've check the receiving of string from server and adding message function. everything is running fine except that the jscrollpanel wont update for first 2 clicks.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution. I need to validate the JPanel in my JScrollPanel.

```
JPanel container
JScrollPanel(container)
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
    container.validate();
});
```